# Laravel task scheduler not running

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have the following method in my `Kernel.php` (the one under `Console` of course):

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->exec("touch lorem.txt")->everyMinute();
}
```

And I have the following cronjob added through the cpanel:

```
* * * * * cd /home/oeit/oe && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I am supposed to see a `lorem.txt` file in the disk. However when I search for it using `find / -name "lorem.txt"` the file doesn't appear, which makes me believe that my cronjob is not working properly. I am on a shared hosting.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to specify the full path for the php executable:

```
* * * * * cd /home/oeit/oe && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on shared hosting, it's entirely possible that it is running, but you don't have access to use `$schedule->exec` on the server.

I would take a look in the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file to see if you are getting any errors.